# How to pass hidden data in HTML list item

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

(Go easy on me I'm just learning HTML/JavaScript)

I want a list that displays only a persons name, but then when the list item is clicked, I want to know about the rest of that persons data.

For example, given the below JSON data, if I click on "Sally" I want to have access to that Sally's age and gender (there could be multiple Sally's).

```
[
  {
    "name": "Charlie",
    "age": "9",
    "gender":"M"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "43",
    "gender": "F"
  },
  {
    "name": "Will",
    "age": "20",
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "18",
    "gender": "F"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to add extra information to a list item without displaying it? Something like

`<li class="list-item" age="18" gender="F">Sally</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`data-` attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to add extra information. Something like:

```
<li class="list-item" data-age="18" data-gender="F">Sally</li>
```

For detailed explanation and knowing how to use this in javascript, css etc. you can see this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

On click of that element you should get the data of that particular node, than match it against your data set using an array filter. You can see more on array filter here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // handle click
    console.log(item)
    // data would be the array of objects, you provided
    let result = data.filter(person => person.name == item.innerText);
    // this would return two elements from your array with "Sally"
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```